# Why are DispatcherObject.CheckAccess() and VerifyAccess() hidden from Intellisense?

Tags: .net-3.5, intellisense

The `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject` class (which `DependencyObject` is based on) contains a useful function, called `CheckAccess()`, that determines whether or not the code is running on the UI thread.

When I wanted to use it yesterday, I was puzzled to find out that Intellisense didn't show the function (nor `VerifyAccess()`, which throws an exception when not on the UI thread), even though the MSDN library lists it. I decided to investigate the class using Reflector. It seems that the function in question has an `EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)` attribute attached to it. The `Dispatcher` class, which is used by `DispatcherObject`, has the same attribute attached to `CheckAccess()` and `VerifyAccess()`:

```
public abstract class DispatcherObject
{
    // ...

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public bool CheckAccess();
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public void VerifyAccess();

    // ...

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    public Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; }
}


public sealed class Dispatcher
{
    // ...

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public bool CheckAccess();
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public void VerifyAccess();

    // ...
}
```

I don't believe that the application of that attribute is random (or a joke), so my question is: why is it there? Should those methods not be called directly? Then why aren't they `protected` (or `internal`, like some of the most useful methods in the WPF)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Microsoft employee [recently stated](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/bd0e6f6c-cadd-48f1-8e1a-163c2f17e4ca/) CheckAccess is used only for "advanced scenarios", so they hid it from Intellisense.

> "CheckAccess and VerifyAccess have
>   always been marked to be not visible,
>   maybe IntelliSense wasn't respecting
>   it.  You can use Reflector to confirm.
>   The idea here is that CheckAccess and
>   VerifyAccess are advances scenarios,
>   that normal developers don't need.
>
> However, I do think that
>   EditorBrowsableState.Advanced would
>   have been a more appropriate level."

There's a Microsoft Connect case for this shortcoming. [Vote for it](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=367777) if it's important to you.

Comment: Microsoft Connect page listed above is no longer available. Here's a new report, in case anyone wants to continue to lobby to change this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3133453

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any documentation that says you shouldn't use those methods directly, but I haven't looked very long.

Also you refer to the EditorVisibleAttribute, which doesn't exist. According to Reflector it's the [EditorBrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx).

Reflector disassembly:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public bool CheckAccess()
{
//CODE
}
```