# What happened to Control.InvokeRequired in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I am writing a small WPF app which spawns some number of threads to stress test a page of a website. I would like to output some information in the textbox of the wpf form of state of the thread I am manually starting from the main WPF thread. I was kind of expecting the WPF to have the same capabilities as far as synchronizing my threads back to the GUI thread through:

```
  if(this.InvokeRequired)
       this.Invoke(ProcessState);
```

However there is nothing of the sorts in the WPF... what are the options to do the output from a non-gui thread in WPF?

**Edit:**
The issue now appears to be in the fact that I am not able to check for the method `CheckAccess()` of the `Dispatcher` object of my control. I am running the 3.5 version of .net and VS 2008 SP1.

Here is the full metadata of my Dispatcher Class (F12 on it):

```
  using MS.Internal.WindowsBase;
  using System;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Security;
  using System.Threading;

  namespace System.Windows.Threading
  {
     // Summary:
//     Provides services for managing the queue of work items for a thread.
public sealed class Dispatcher
{
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher for the thread currently executing
    //     and creates a new System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher if one is not already
    //     associated with the thread.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The dispatcher associated with the current thread.
    public static Dispatcher CurrentDispatcher { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Determines whether the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher has finished shutting
    //     down.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     true if the dispatcher has finished shutting down; otherwise, false.
    public bool HasShutdownFinished { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Determines whether the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher is shutting down.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     true if the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher has started shutting down;
    //     otherwise, false.
    public bool HasShutdownStarted { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the collection of hooks that provide additional event information about
    //     the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The hooks associated with this System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    public DispatcherHooks Hooks { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the thread this System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher is associated with.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The thread.
    public Thread Thread { get; }

    // Summary:
    //     Occurs when the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher finishes shutting down.
    public event EventHandler ShutdownFinished;
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Occurs when the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher begins to shut down.
    public event EventHandler ShutdownStarted;
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Occurs when a thread exception is thrown and uncaught during execution of
    //     a delegate by way of Overload:System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke
    //     or Overload:System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.
    public event DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler UnhandledException;
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Occurs when a thread exception is thrown and uncaught during execution of
    //     a delegate by way of Overload:System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke
    //     or Overload:System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke when in the filter
    //     stage.
    public event DispatcherUnhandledExceptionFilterEventHandler UnhandledExceptionFilter;

    public DispatcherOperation BeginInvoke(Delegate method, params object[] args);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Executes the specified delegate asynchronously at the specified priority
    //     on the thread the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher is associated with.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   priority:
    //     The priority, relative to the other pending operations in the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     event queue, the specified method is invoked.
    //
    //   method:
    //     The delegate to a method that takes no arguments, which is pushed onto the
    //     System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher event queue.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An object, which is returned immediately after Overload:System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
    //     is called, that can be used to interact with the delegate as it is pending
    //     execution in the event queue.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     method is null.
    //
    //   System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException:
    //     priority is not a valid System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public DispatcherOperation BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method);
    public DispatcherOperation BeginInvoke(Delegate method, DispatcherPriority priority, params object[] args);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Executes the specified delegate asynchronously at the specified priority
    //     and with the specified argument on the thread the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     is associated with.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   priority:
    //     The priority, relative to the other pending operations in the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     event queue, the specified method is invoked.
    //
    //   method:
    //     A delegate to a method that takes one argument, which is pushed onto the
    //     System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher event queue.
    //
    //   arg:
    //     The object to pass as an argument to the specified method.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An object, which is returned immediately after Overload:System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
    //     is called, that can be used to interact with the delegate as it is pending
    //     execution in the event queue.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     method is null.
    //
    //   System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException:
    //     priority is not a valid System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public DispatcherOperation BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, object arg);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Executes the specified delegate asynchronously at the specified priority
    //     and with the specified array of arguments on the thread the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     is associated with.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   priority:
    //     The priority, relative to the other pending operations in the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     event queue, the specified method is invoked.
    //
    //   method:
    //     A delegate to a method that takes multiple arguments, which is pushed onto
    //     the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher event queue.
    //
    //   arg:
    //     The object to pass as an argument to the specified method.
    //
    //   args:
    //     An array of objects to pass as arguments to the specified method.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An object, which is returned immediately after Overload:System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
    //     is called, that can be used to interact with the delegate as it is pending
    //     execution in the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher queue.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     method is null.
    //
    //   System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException:
    //     System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority is not a valid priority.
    [Browsable(false)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public DispatcherOperation BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, object arg, params object[] args);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initiates shutdown of the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher asynchronously.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   priority:
    //     The priority at which to begin shutting down the dispatcher.
    [SecurityCritical]
    public void BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority priority);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Determines whether the calling thread is the thread associated with this
    //     System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     true if the calling thread is the thread associated with this System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher;
    //     otherwise, false.
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public bool CheckAccess();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Disables processing of the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher queue.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A structure used to re-enable dispatcher processing.
    public DispatcherProcessingDisabled DisableProcessing();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Requests that all frames exit, including nested frames.
    [SecurityCritical]
    public static void ExitAllFrames();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher for the specified thread.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   thread:
    //     The thread to obtain the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher from.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The dispatcher for thread.
    public static Dispatcher FromThread(Thread thread);
    public object Invoke(Delegate method, params object[] args);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Executes the specified delegate synchronously at the specified priority on
    //     the thread on which the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher is associated
    //     with.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   priority:
    //     The priority, relative to the other pending operations in the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     event queue, the specified method is invoked.
    //
    //   method:
    //     A delegate to a method that takes no arguments, which is pushed onto the
    //     System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher event queue.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The return value from the delegate being invoked or null if the delegate
    //     has no return value.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentException:
    //     priority is equal to System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Inactive.
    //
    //   System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException:
    //     priority is not a valid priority.
    //
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     method is null.
    [Browsable(false)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public object Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method);
    public object Invoke(Delegate method, DispatcherPriority priority, params object[] args);
    public object Invoke(Delegate method, TimeSpan timeout, params object[] args);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Executes the specified delegate at the specified priority with the specified
    //     argument synchronously on the thread the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     is associated with.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   priority:
    //     The priority, relative to the other pending operations in the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     event queue, the specified method is invoked.
    //
    //   method:
    //     A delegate to a method that takes one argument, which is pushed onto the
    //     System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher event queue.
    //
    //   arg:
    //     An object to pass as an argument to the given method.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The return value from the delegate being invoked or null if the delegate
    //     has no return value.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentException:
    //     priority is equal to System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Inactive.
    //
    //   System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException:
    //     priority is not a valid priority.
    //
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     method is null.
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public object Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, object arg);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Executes the specified delegate synchronously at the specified priority and
    //     with the specified time-out value on the thread the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     was created.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   priority:
    //     The priority, relative to the other pending operations in the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     event queue, the specified method is invoked.
    //
    //   timeout:
    //     The maximum time to wait for the operation to finish.
    //
    //   method:
    //     The delegate to a method that takes no arguments, which is pushed onto the
    //     System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher event queue.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The return value from the delegate being invoked or null if the delegate
    //     has no return value.
    [Browsable(false)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public object Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method);
    public object Invoke(Delegate method, TimeSpan timeout, DispatcherPriority priority, params object[] args);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Executes the specified delegate at the specified priority with the specified
    //     arguments synchronously on the thread the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     is associated with.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   priority:
    //     The priority, relative to the other pending operations in the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     event queue, the specified method is invoked.
    //
    //   method:
    //     A delegate to a method that takes multiple arguments, which is pushed onto
    //     the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher event queue.
    //
    //   arg:
    //     An object to pass as an argument to the given method.
    //
    //   args:
    //     An array of objects to pass as arguments to the given method.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The return value from the delegate being invoked or null if the delegate
    //     has no return value.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentException:
    //     priority is equal to System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Inactive.
    //
    //   System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException:
    //     priority is not a valid priority.
    //
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     method is null.
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public object Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, object arg, params object[] args);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Executes the specified delegate at the specified priority with the specified
    //     argument synchronously on the thread the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     is associated with.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   priority:
    //     The priority, relative to the other pending operations in the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     event queue, the specified method is invoked.
    //
    //   timeout:
    //     The maximum time to wait for the operation to finish.
    //
    //   method:
    //     A delegate to a method that takes multiple arguments, which is pushed onto
    //     the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher event queue.
    //
    //   arg:
    //     An object to pass as an argument to the given method. This can be null if
    //     no arguments are needed.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The return value from the delegate being invoked or null if the delegate
    //     has no return value.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentException:
    //     priority is equal to System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Inactive.
    //
    //   System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException:
    //     priority is not a valid priority.
    //
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     method is null.
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public object Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, object arg);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Executes the specified delegate at the specified priority with the specified
    //     arguments synchronously on the thread the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     is associated with.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   priority:
    //     The priority, relative to the other pending operations in the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     event queue, the specified method is invoked.
    //
    //   timeout:
    //     The maximum time to wait for the operation to finish.
    //
    //   method:
    //     A delegate to a method that takes multiple arguments, which is pushed onto
    //     the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher event queue.
    //
    //   arg:
    //     An object to pass as an argument to the specified method.
    //
    //   args:
    //     An array of objects to pass as arguments to the specified method.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The return value from the delegate being invoked or null if the delegate
    //     has no return value.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentException:
    //     priority is equal to System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Inactive.
    //
    //   System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException:
    //     priority is not a valid System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.
    //
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     method is null.
    [Browsable(false)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public object Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, object arg, params object[] args);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initiates the shutdown process of the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher
    //     synchronously.
    [SecurityCritical]
    public void InvokeShutdown();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Enters an execute loop.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   frame:
    //     The frame for the dispatcher to process.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     frame is null.
    //
    //   System.InvalidOperationException:
    //     System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.HasShutdownFinished is true -or- frame
    //     is running on a different System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.  -or- Dispatcher
    //     processing has been disabled.
    [SecurityCritical]
    public static void PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Pushes the main execution frame on the event queue of the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.
    [SecurityCritical]
    public static void Run();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Determines whether the specified System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority
    //     is a valid priority.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   priority:
    //     The priority to check.
    //
    //   parameterName:
    //     A string that will be returned by the exception that occurs if the priority
    //     is invalid.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException:
    //     priority is not a valid System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.
    public static void ValidatePriority(DispatcherPriority priority, string parameterName);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Determines whether the calling thread has access to this System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.InvalidOperationException:
    //     The calling thread does not have access to this System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public void VerifyAccess();
}
```

}

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In WPF, this was moved out of the Control/UIElement hierarchy, and into the dispatcher.

The equivelent is [Dispatcher.CheckAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess.aspx) and [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647509.aspx).

You should be able to do:

```
if (someControl.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
      UpdateUI();
else
    someControl.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(UpdateUI));
```

---

Your metadata includes:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Determines whether the calling thread is the thread associated with this
//     System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.
//
// Returns:
//     true if the calling thread is the thread associated with this System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher;
//     otherwise, false.
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public bool CheckAccess();
```

This is the method you want to use...  It doesn't show up in Intellisense, but it is there, and it does work correctly.

Comment: @Reed, I am suspecting bc of the fact that I am under 3.5 there is no CheckAccess() on the Dispatcher class of the control, any ideas?

Comment: @The Chad Who Loved Me: It should exist: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess(v=VS.90).aspx   (That's the 3.5 version)  Make sure to add `using System.Windows.Threading;` if you want to work with Dispatcher, too.

Comment: @Reed, I don't have that assembly listed as part of the .net under add reference. Is it hidden somewhere as part of the .net framework?

Comment: @The Chad: It's a standard WPF assembly.  If you're in 3.5 (even 3.0), and a WPF project, it should be avaialble...

Comment: @Reed,posted an Edit to the post with the metadata of the .net Dispatcher class...Still no CheckAccess() method to be seen.

Comment: @The Chad: This won't show up in Intellisense (for some stupid reason, it's flaged as not browsable), but it IS there, even in your metadata...

Comment: @The Chad: Does it not compile or is it not showing up in intellisense? The check access method is hidden from intellisense for some reason. A [related stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500/why-are-dispatcherobject-checkaccess-and-verifyaccess-hidden-from-intellisens).

Answer (score 3):

If you're just converting WinForm Invoke to to WPF Dispatch, just a few small changes are needed to convert your WinForm code to the WPF code. This worked for my control named "_connection", and was rewritten to work in a WPF application.

```
// ---- Original WinForm code ----
delegate void SetIndicatorCallback(bool bVal);

private void SetIndicator(bool bVal)
{
   if (this._connection.InvokeRequired)
   {
      SetIndicatorCallback d = new SetIndicatorCallback(SetIndicator);
      this.Invoke(d, new object[] { bVal });
   }
   else
   {
      if (bVal)
      {
           // Change the control's color, or whatever action is required.
      }

   }
}

// ---- WPF ----

// Still using a delegate 
delegate void SetIndicatorCallback(bool bVal);


private void SetIndicator(bool bVal)
    {
        if (this._connection.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
          if (bVal)
          {
                // Change the control' color, or whatever action is needed.
          }
        }
        else
        { 
           SetIndicatorCallback d = new SetIndicatorCallback(SetIndicator);
           this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { bVal });
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

For me that worked on every Page, UserControl and Frame

```
  Implements IDisposable 'Code is implemented automatically
  Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        AddHandler Me.Dispatcher.ShutdownStarted, AddressOf Me_HasShutDownStarted

    End Sub


    Private Sub Me_HasShutDownStarted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If Me.disposedValue = False Then Call Me.Dispose()
    End Sub
```