# C# wpf dispatcher confusion

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher, invokerequired

how should i go about porting this code to wpf?

```
public void ChangeTextBox(string txt)
    {
        if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new UpdateText(ChangeTextBox), new object[] { txt });
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += txt + "\r\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Format, spell, and capitalize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
public void ChangeTextBox(string txt)
    {
        if (!textBox1.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            textBox1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateText(ChangeTextBox), new object[] { txt });
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += txt + "\r\n";
        }
    }
```

This answer was based upon a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436349/what-happened-to-control-invokerequired-in-wpf) and the [MSDN Documentation for Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `Dispatcher` class of the control or the Application level `Dispatcher` but in your case you want the control's dispatcher. Also, note that I don't have to recursively call the calling method to invoke it. I can just simply set the `textBox.Text` to what value you want.

What happens is that it does `Context switch` behind the scenes and thus allowing your control to be modified because it is being dispatched to its own dispatcher.

```
if(!textBox1.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
 textbox1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox.Text += txt + "\r\n";);
}
else
{
 textBox.Text += txt + "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: You need to Call CheckAccess on the Dispatcher related to textBox1...not on the text box itself ;)

Comment: @YoupTube Sorry, I was typing it on the spot. Corrected. Thanks

Comment: @III,@YoupTube - `textBox1.CheckAccess()` will work too because textBox derives from `DispatcherObject` where `CheckAccess()` method is defined.

Comment: @RohitVats That's true. This is what happens when you just woke up and went straight to SO.