# How to keep the UI responsive while doing background tasks

Tags: c#, wpf

I have implemented a refresh button, which reads the database and checks for any new entrys and adds them to an `ObservableCollection`. I have a refresh icon which spins dependsing on the value of `IsRefreshing`. Like so:

```
new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            IsRefreshing = true;

            //Reads database
            //ObservableCollection.Add(NewValues)

            IsRefreshing = false;
        }).Start();
```

But running this gives me the exception:

> This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

I am obviously going about this the wrong way, but not sure how I should how to keep the UI responsive while doing background tasks?

Comment: You should never access controls that created in the main thread by other thread.

Comment: Don't use raw threads, uase async/await and tasks. ADO.NET and EF already support asynchronous execution. In any case you can't modify the UI from another thread

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436349/what-happened-to-control-invokerequired-in-wpf

Comment: Post the event handler's code and the code that reads from the database. The current code with `Thread` should be removed

Comment: @spender there's no reason to use Invoke or BeginInvoke since .NET 4.5. Hard-coded access from background threads to the UI is a bad idea anyway

Comment: Start reading here: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify the UI from a background thread. All supported .NET versions allow using `async/await` to execute something in the background and get back to the UI thread.

ADO.NET, Entity Framework, Dapper and most ORMs support asynchronous execution. For example, ADO.NET's `ExecuteReader` has an equivalent `ExecuteReaderAsync` method. EF's `ToList()` has a `ToListAsync()`. Dapper's `Query` has `QueryAsync`

You should change your event handler to something like this :

```
private async void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_cnString)
    {
        IsRefreshing = true;
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        var results=await connection.QueryAsync<Value>(query);
        //We're now back in the UI thread
        _theCollection.AddRange(results);
        IsRefreshing = false;
    }
}
```

When `OpenAsync` or `QueryAsync` are called, .NET will run the query in the background and release the current (UI) thread. When the query completes `await` ensures that execution will resume on the original thread, ie the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to add this item to the collection but you have to do it on the Dispatcher thread like so:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ObservableCollection.Add(NewValues));
```

Comment: Not needed when `await` is available. If you want to post progress updates from another task or thread, use the Progress<T> class. Using it is described in [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

Comment: Besides, `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` can deadlock the application if the UI thread is busy

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't see much code from his part but you assume whole lot. If he is trying to add to a observable collection that is binded to some ListView or simillar control than he cannot do that since UI cannot be updated from any other thread than UI. Therefore the adding to the observable collection needs to happen on the UI thread. This is why you cal the Invoke on the Dispatcher.

Comment: I don't assume. After `await` you are back in the UI thread. That means you can modify any element. That's why there's no need to use Invoke. I suggest you check the link I provided

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The only thing I see is him opening a whole different thread and doing his work in this thread. If he want's to update an UI element from this thread he has to call it on the UI thread. No other way than to call Dispatcher.Invoke

Comment: The only "assumption" I make is that the OP is using a *supported* .NET runtime version, ie 4.5.2 and later

Comment: Read the link please. `BeginInvoke`  was required only up to .NET 4.0. No need for it since 2012 when .NET 4.5 came out. As for why `Invoke` is a bad idea, you'll find a *lot* of SO questions complaining about deadlocked UIs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There is absolutely no way of me knowing how his application looks like. Did he inherit the application? Can he afford to go through application and change the model to async/await or does he open up Threads the old way? He gave a problem and I presented a solution. On the other hand just because there are a lot of SO questions complaining about deadlocked UI, doesn't mean this model is wrong. You will also find alot of SO questions about C++ pointers leading nowhere. Doesn't mean pointers are bad and all shold avoid them!