# WPF Binding not working when using different data model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm creating an app which monitors several trace servers on remote machines and displays the processed data on a UI. When I'm using a simulator generating the data everything works as expected. The issue is that the UI is not being updated when the actual data model is used. Sometimes its updated once after startup, sometimes never. The ViewModel is untouched and the data is correctly processed and available. This affects all controls which are using binding in XAML. Other controls which are updated in code behind work as expected.
The ViewModels all properly implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

See the following example:

[TimeStrip user control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3DyB.png)

In this `TimeStrip` control the textbox and line should move to the right with time.

**UserControl XAML:**

```
<Grid  x:Name="TimeSlotGrid">
         //..
    <local:TimeSlot Grid.Column="2" Text="8:00"/>
    <local:TimeSlot Grid.Column="3" Text="9:00"/>
        //...
</Grid>          
<Grid LayoutUpdated="Grid_LayoutUpdated" Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
    <Canvas x:Name="TimeCanvas">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MediumTextTheme}" 
                   Text="{Binding Path=UiStuff.CurrentTimeString}" 
                   Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=UiStuff.TimeTextPos}" 
                   Canvas.Top="1"/>
        <Line x:Name="CurrentTimeCursor" 
              X1="{Binding Path=UiStuff.TimePos}" 
              X2="{Binding Path=UiStuff.TimePos}" 
              Y1="0" Y2="360" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

The gray boxes (`TimeSlot`) are updated with `Grid_LayoutUpdated` which sets their background gradient according to the current time:

**Code behind**

```
private void Grid_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        MainViewModel context = DataContext as MainViewModel;
        context.UiStuff.GridWidth = TimeCanvas.ActualWidth;
        DateTime dt = context.UiStuff.CurrentTime;
        int currentHour = dt.AddHours(-6).Hour;
        double currentHourPart = dt.Minute / 60d;
        for (int i = 0; i < TimeSlotGrid.Children.Count; i++)
        {
            TimeSlot slot = TimeSlotGrid.Children[i] as TimeSlot;
            if (slot is null) continue;
            slot.Visibility = i <= currentHour ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
            slot.Background = Brushes.Gray;
            if (i == currentHour)
            {
               lgb.GradientStops[1].Offset = currentHourPart;
               lgb.GradientStops[2].Offset = currentHourPart;
               slot.Background = lgb;
             }
         }
}
```

**ViewModel (minimal)**

```
public class MainViewModel 
{
        public UIElements UiStuff { get; set; } 
        private readonly TraceCommunication Trace;
        
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Trace = new TraceCommunication();
            Trace.MessageReceived += Trace_MessageReceived;
            Trace.StartConnection("10.128.251.136", "9334");
        }
        
        private void Trace_MessageReceived(DataRow message)
        {
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(values[Columns.TimeStamp].ToString(), out DateTime dt)) return;

            UiStuff.CurrentTime = dt;
        }
}

public class UIElements : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        
        private DateTime currentTime;
        public DateTime CurrentTime
        {
            get => currentTime;
            set
            {
                currentTime = value;
                CurrentTimeString = currentTime.ToString("HH:mm");
                double timescale = currentTime.AddHours(-6).TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes / 1440;
                TimePos = (int)(GridWidth * timescale);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        
        private string currenTimeString;

        public string CurrentTimeString
        {
            get => currenTimeString;
            set { currenTimeString = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
        }   
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot the bindings were only updated once after startup (9:51). The `TimeSlots` are properly displayed (its 10:30).

As mentioned, this all works when the simulator is used. The only difference is in the `TraceCommunication` object, which monitors the remote system. The ViewModel subscribes to the `MessageReceived` event and sets the UI elements accordingly.

```
public class TraceCommunication
{
        internal delegate void TraceEventHandler(DataRow value);
        internal event TraceEventHandler MessageReceived;
        
        private TraceEngineIntf traceEngine;

        private string _Ip;
        private string _Port; 
        
        public TraceCommunication()
        {
            //...
        }

        internal bool StartConnection(string ip, string port)
        {
            _Ip = ip;
            _Port = port;
            bool success = true;
            if (!ip.Contains("."))
            {
                TraceSimulator Sim = new TraceSimulator(ip);
                Sim.MessageReceived +=  FireEventIfRelevant;
                Sim.StartTracing();
            }
            else
            {
                traceEngine = new TraceEngineIntf();
                traceEngine.ConnectedChanged += Trace_ConnectedChanged;
                traceEngine.MessageReceived += FireEventIfRelevant;
                success = traceEngine.SetHost(_Ip, _Port);
            }
            return success;
        }
        
        private void FireEventIfRelevant(DataRow row)
        {
            if (!TraceFilter.IsRelevant(row)) return;
            MessageReceived?.Invoke(row);
        }
        
        private void Trace_ConnectedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            traceEngine = sender as TraceEngineIntf;

            if (traceEngine.Connected)
            {
                traceEngine.StartRead();
            }
            else
            {
                Connect();
            }
        }
}
```

In both cases the data is received and processed correctly. The events are fired and then handled properly in the ViewModel. But the UI responses only when the simulator is used.
This was not always the case. I started using only the real thing which worked fine. Later I implemented the simulator when I needed more data faster for development.

I'm out of ideas what might cause this behavior.
Does anyone know what's going on or can give me hint what to check next?

Thanks!

Comment: On what thread app receives events?

Comment: @MaxNaumov Actually I don't know. I have no access to 'TraceEngineIntf', since its third party. When the 'traceEngine' is connected, it starts reading. I added that in the question. 
My 'Sim.StartTracing()' is an async void which periodically fires the events.

Comment: You can check it via debug in your code. If it's other than UI thread you should handle UI updates on UI thread. In this question you can find how to check if you need to use invocation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436349/what-happened-to-control-invokerequired-in-wpf

Comment: If the viewmodels properly implement inotifypropertychanged then property changed notification would be marshalled across threads. I don't see a viewmodel in the question. Lots of code but no viewmodel. You should show us a minimal reproduction of your problem rather than loads of code. I also suggest you use snoop to check the instance of viewmodel that changes properties is really the one is data context.

Comment: @Andy I added the ViewModel to the question. I also checked the data context with snoop, it is the actual instance of the ViewModel  with the changed properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TimeStrip` control contains 24 `TimeSlot` controls representing the hours of the day. It broke when I set the BackGround of the current `TimeSlot` to a `LinearGradientBrush` instead of a solid `Brush` in the `Grid_LayoutUpdated` handler method of `TimeStrip`.

I fixed it by passing the "currentHourPart" as a dependency property to the `TimeSlot` itself and setting the gradient there accordingly.

I still don't know why that caused the issue and why it worked when I used the simulator.